# Laplace smoothig for Bayesian Netoworks in bnlearn

Tags: r, bayesian, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I'm trying to work with Bayesian Networks using R and currently I am using `bnlearn` framework.
I'm trying to use score based structural learning from data and try different algorithms and approaches.

I would like to know if there is Laplace smoothing implemented in `bnlearn` or not. I could not find any information about it in the documentation. Am I missing somethings? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. However, this should be no problem as different priors are available in `bnlearn` and, unless you have some very specific reason to use Laplace smoothing, which is one particular prior, these should do.

Once you have a structure, you learn parameters with the `bn.fit()` function. Setting `method = "bayes"` uses Bayesian estimation and the optional argument `iss` determines the prior. The definition of `iss`: "the imaginary sample size used by the bayes method to estimate the conditional probability tables (CPTs) associated with discrete nodes".

As an example, consder a binary root node X in some network. `bn.fit()` returns `(Nx + iss / cptsize) / (N + iss)` as the probability of `X = x`, where `N` is your number of samples, `Nx` the number of samples with `X = x`, and `cptsize` the cardinality of `X`; in this case `cptsize = 2` because `X` is binary. Laplace correction would require that  `iss / cptsize` always be equal to 1. Yet, `bnlearn` uses the same `iss` value for all CPTs and, `iss / cptsize` will only be 1 if all variables have the same cardinality. Thus, for binary variables, you could indeed have Laplace correction by setting `iss = 2`. In the general case, however, it is not possible.

See [bnlearn::bn.fit difference and calculation of methods "mle" and "bayes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945372/bnlearnbn-fit-difference-and-calculation-of-methods-mle-and-bayes/52017677#52017677) for some additional details.