# bnlearn::bn.fit difference and calculation of methods "mle" and "bayes"

Tags: r, bayesian, bayesian-networks, mle, bnlearn

I try to understand the differences between the two methods `bayes` and `mle` in the `bn.fit` function of the package `bnlearn`.

I know about the debate between the frequentist and the bayesian approach on understanding probabilities. On a theoretical level I suppose the maximum likelihood estimate `mle` is a simple frequentist approach setting the relative frequencies as the probability. But what calculations are done to get the `bayes` estimate? I already checked out the [bnlearn documenation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnlearn/bnlearn.pdf), the [description of the bn.fit function](http://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/bn.fit.html) and some [application examples](https://kevintshoemaker.github.io/NRES-746/Bayes_Network_Markdown_Final.html), but nowhere there's a real description of what's happening.

I also tried to understand the function in R by first checking out `bnlearn::bn.fit`, leading to `bnlearn:::bn.fit.backend`, leading to `bnlearn:::smartSapply` but then I got stuck.

Some help would be really appreciated as I use the package for academic work and therefore I should be able to explain what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bayesian parameter estimation in `bnlearn::bn.fit` applies to discrete variables. The key is the optional `iss` argument: "the imaginary sample size used by the bayes method to estimate the conditional probability tables (CPTs) associated with discrete nodes".

So, for a binary root node `X` in some network, the `bayes` option in `bnlearn::bn.fit` returns `(Nx + iss / cptsize) / (N + iss)` as the probability of `X = x`, where `N` is your number of samples, `Nx` the number of samples with `X = x`, and `cptsize` the size of the CPT of `X`; in this case `cptsize = 2`. The relevant code is in the `bnlearn:::bn.fit.backend.discrete` function, in particular the line: `tab = tab + extra.args$iss/prod(dim(tab))`

Thus, `iss / cptsize` is the number of imaginary observations for each entry in a CPT, as opposed to `N`, the number of 'real' observations. With `iss = 0` you would be getting a maximum likelihood estimate, as you would have no prior imaginary observations.

The higher `iss` with respect to `N`, the stronger the effect of the prior on your posterior parameter estimates. With a fixed `iss` and a growing `N`, the  Bayesian estimator and the maximum likelihood estimator converge to the same value.

A common rule of thumb is to use a small non-zero `iss` so that you avoid zero entries in the CPTs, corresponding to combinations that were not observed in the data. Such zero entries could then result in a network which generalizes poorly, such as some early versions of the [Pathfinder system](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~koller/BNtut/sld138.htm).

For more details on Bayesian parameter estimation you can have a look at the book by [Koller and Friedman](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models). I suppose many other Bayesian network books also cover the topic.

Comment: Great answer, great insight! Is there a default non-zero value for iss? Again, no details in the documentation...

Comment: I would guess not. Since nothing is documented, the only safe thing is to assume nothing and always provide an `iss` value together with `method = bayes`. I think this is lacking because there is no general rule to determine an adequate value, so it is left up to the user to decide. Basically, any small value, with respect to the number of instances, will do. I often use 0.01.